# XAML designer not showing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

Drag and drop view of the XAML designer is not visible, even after trying different options in Tools in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: What type of proj? Are you using a fully updated copy of Win10?

Comment: Its a Universal Windows 10 Project.

Comment: I had this exact same problem in a UWP IoT proj until I got the most recent updates for Win10 and it was fine.

Comment: Ok cool, let me try get the updates from our infrastructure team

Comment: Have you tried to change the target version of your project to the Build 10240 ? It's in the properties in the App in the part Application > Targeting. The designer seems not working with the build 10586.

Comment: Yes, you are right the 10586 build has some compatibility issues with OS. When I reverted the target to 10240, the designer seems to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There are 2 options to do it....Either update your OS to latest version 1511, 10586 (as in screenshot) or change the target version to 10.0 Build 10240.

Comment: I got my OS updated with latest build 1511 and now everything seems to work fine.